# Leaflet multiple popups based on click-event

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to get multiple (5) popups to open based on clicking a polyline.
It seems that I am only able to open one of the popups/photo with the clickevent.
Is it possible to open 5 popups via one click on a polyline in Leaflet?

```
function getPhotos(res) {
  const photo_link = `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/number/photos?photo_sources=true&access_token=hidden&size=1000`;
  fetch(photo_link)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(function (data) {
      for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        var images = data[x].urls["1000"];
        console.log(images);
        var lat = data[x].location[0];
        var lng = data[x].location[1];
        var latlng = { lat, lng };
        console.log(latlng);
        L.polyline(coordinates, {
          color: "red",
          weight: 3,
        })
          .on("click", function (e) {
            L.popup({ autoPan: false })
              .setContent("<img src='" + images + "' width='160'/>")
              .setLatLng(latlng)
              .openOn(map);
          })

          .addTo(map);
      }
    });
}
getPhotos();
```

Comment: This is unclear. Why 5? What would be the positions of those popups in relation with the polyline? What's the value of the `coordinates` variable at runtime, since it looks undefined?

Answer (score 0):

```
var layer= new L.popup({ autoPan: false, autoClose: false })

                                .setContent("<img src='" + images + "' width='160'/>")
                                .setLatLng(latlng)
                            map.addLayer(layer)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.